# How to get alfresco version number programmatically

Tags: version, alfresco

I am using Alfresco. I know how to see installed Alfresco vesrion number, but I need to get this version number programmatically, for example via rest API or some http request. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The REST API that Share uses to get the data from the repo is (e.g.):

```
http://localhost:8081/share/proxy/alfresco/api/server
```

This  returns:

```
{
   data: {
      edition: "Enterprise",
      version: "5.0.0",
      schema: "8002"
   }
}
```

That webscript is this one: https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/master/projects/remote-api/config/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/server.get.desc.xml

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript code you can use the server object:

```
server.version
server.versionMajor
server.versionMinor
server.versionRevision
server.edition
```

In Java you can use the DescriptorService, for example:

```
serviceRegistry.getDescriptorService().getCurrentRepositoryDescriptor().getVersion()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Browser Binding" API of the CMIS protocol.

In particular, read this property:

```
productVersion
```

Reference: http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/cs01/CMIS-v1.1-cs01.html#x1-1660002 paragraph 2.2.2.2.2

Advantage over the other methods: CMIS is a standard so this operation will always be available, unlike the Share webscripts which might change. Also, your code will be compatible with any other CMIS implementation.

Here is an example of how [CMIS via JavaScript](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/WebCMIS/blob/master/src/index.html) works.